# How to parse the List data type in Bash

Tags: bash, list

Context: Making some AWS API calls from Bash which give me a List Of Ids.
I am stuck at being able to parse it, and how do I pass it as an argument to a function.

Test Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
input_data in format:


[
        "d-1",
    
        "d-2",
    
        "d-3",
    
        "d-4"
    
    ]
     # None of the following calls work
     # assume lst=<above data type>
     echo "1. $lst"
    
     echo "2. ${lst[*]}"
    
     echo "3. ${lst[@]}"
```

Any Pointers would be much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: The return from the API calls normally comes back in JSON format and so use jq to parse the returned data

Answer (score 1):

If you mean an *array* in `bash` (your original question seemed to indicate the input file was actual `bash` code), that uses `()` rather than `[]`:

```
lst=("d-1" "d-2" "d-3" "pax is awesome")
echo "${lst[3]}"                           # Specific zero-based item.
for item in "${lst[@]}" ; do               # Process all items.
    echo "${item}"
done
```

The output of that is, as expected:

```
pax is awesome
d-1
d-2
d-3
pax is awesome
```

---

However, if you're actually getting JSON from the API, `jq` is a good tool to use, an example being shown in the following transcript:

```
pax:~> cat json.in
[
    "d-1",
    "d-2",
    "d-3"
]

pax:~> idList=($(jq '.[]' json.in))
pax:~> for item in ${idList[@]} ; do echo ${item} ; done
"d-1"
"d-2"
"d-3"
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, unfortunately the above data type is what I get as in input from an external API call. Maybe I should just convert it into a string and parse it using Other Unix tools vs using bash.

Comment: @abhi09: apologies, your original question seemed to indicate the input file format was `bash` code rather than an input. Have adjusted answer to suit but yes, bottom line is to just use a tool like `jq` to process the JSON-like input.

Comment: I solved the original question by using sed:
`
echo $deployment_ids | sed 's/[][]//g'| sed 's/ //g' | xargs`